# Cant get mediaplayer sound on Android 9,10 Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im using this code on the android 8 and below but on Android version 9+ its not working.

```
MediaPlayer player3;
        player3 = new MediaPlayer();
        player3.SetDataSource(url);
        player3.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
        player3.Completion += mediaPlayer_Completion;
        player3.PrepareAsync();
        player3.Start();
```

EDIT: Im trying to reproduce a audio stream link. The player doesn't do anything. The same code it works fine on another android versions.

Comment: What is not working? What are you attempting to do? What are the effects of it not working? Please provide more detail.

Comment: @JessicaWard Im trying to reproduce a audio stream link. The player doesn't do anything. The same code it works fine on another android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After Android 9 (API level 28), **cleartext support** is disabled
>   by default.

Check https://koz.io/android-m-and-the-war-on-cleartext-traffic/

#### Solution 1

Create file `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your video URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

#### Solution 2

[Android:usesCleartextTraffic Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```