# Bing maps url not downloading tiles and throws security exception

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bing-maps

I am downloading tiles from Bing maps server. Using the below Url, it is working fine in Android and UWP platform. But throw exception “System.Net.WebException: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection” in iOS.

Bing Url:
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Road?output=json&include=providers&key=
I tried the below solution (stack overflow link) but it is not working. Then, I changed http to https (secured Url). It is working fine, and tiles are downloaded from Bing server.

[App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection - IOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712155)

Should we need use secured Url (https:) only in iOS platform for downloading tiles from Bing server.? But, open street maps Url working with http.

Anyone please provide the exact solution why should use secured url for Bing map tiles in iOS.?

Regards,
Bharathi

Comment: You could add the code from the link in info.plist . If you want to use `https` , check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894967/cant-get-mediaplayer-sound-on-android-9-10-xamarin/58897359#58897359

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading tiles directly, best practice is to get the URL for the tiles from the imagery metadata service documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-imagery-metadata
Make sure to use the uriScheme=https if you want to use SSL (which is recommended).

Note that the map controls (which are available natively now for iOS and Android, as well as for UWP) handle this automatically and are much easier to use than working with tiles directly.