# Xamarin Forms Refuse connection a call WS

Tags: c#, xamarin, soap, httpwebrequest

I have this class that works correctly from a console application.
When I incorporate it into my Xamarin Forms project, it gives an error (refused connection) when creating the webrequest.
I would appreciate any help in that regard.

**`using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }`** 
stays dead until causing an exception in Xamarin forms.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFPaG.png)

My code:

```
public class WebServiceSOAP
    {
    var _url = "http://MyDomain/My.asmx";
    var _action = "http://MyDomain/MyMethod";



string sxml = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                 xmlns:adh=""http://Mydomain"">
                 <soapenv:Header/>
                 <soapenv:Body>
                 <adh:MyMethod>
                 <adh:param1>TEST1</adh:param1>
                 <adh:param2>test2</adh:param2>
                 <adh:param3>test3</adh:param3>
                 </adh:MyMethod> 
                 </soapenv:Body>
                 </soapenv:Envelope>";

XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(sxml);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(webRequest.GetResponse()))
{
     HttpStatusCode code = response.StatusCode;
     if (code == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
          using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
          {
               string resp = sr.ReadToEnd();
          }
      }
 }
 }

  private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }

    private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(string sxml)
    {
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(sxml);
        return soapEnvelopeDocument;
    }

    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: After iOS 9.0 and Android 9.0 ,App Transport Security (ATS) enforces secure connections between internet resources (such as the app's back-end server) and the app, thereby preventing accidental disclosure of sensitive information. Since ATS is enabled by default in apps built for iOS 9, all connections will be subject to ATS security requirements. If connections do not meet these requirements, they will fail with an exception. For more details you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/#ASP.NET_Web_Service_ASMX

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for the reply. I have been looking at the link and I have already seen how to configure info.plist to indicate the corresponding exclusions. But on Android, is it possible to configure the manifest to also allow its operation?
[I am testing the app on android phone]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894967/cant-get-mediaplayer-sound-on-android-9-10-xamarin/58897359#58897359

Comment: I just wrote that I have located it but the WS call still doesn't work

Comment: You have to have https instead of http for all the URLs

Comment: Before writing, I changed to https but with the same result. I check again and I comment.
Thank you

Comment: Hello, I have been trying by all means to send a file with https and it still throws the same error. Finally, I have chosen to send the file via FTP and make a call to the ws with another method to download and process it.
Thank you very much for your assistance.